# Where is the psql_history file in Windows's PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, psql

My PostgreSQL version is 9.6 and Windows Server 2012.

but PostgreSQL psql_history file was not found in %APPDATA%\postgresql\psql_history.
How can i find this file?

also, when I input `\s` command for finding command history, alerting message "history is not supported by this installation"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because history is not supported on "native" Windows installations, there is no history file to find.  This is how it works on Windows.

If you want to use command line history on Windows, you can install cygwin and then install psql via cygwin.